# Where to find old Rails 2.3 Guides

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since Rails 3 is out, all the guides on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ are for Rails 3. I used to reference the guides for 2.3 a lot. Is there anywhere they're still available?

Comment: doesn't answer your question but rails2.3 release notes are: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html
There's a fair bit of useful information there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rails 2.3.8 guides can now be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/index.html

Comment: ***THANK YOU!*** It's all well and good to upgrade stuff, but really annoying to hide all the old documentation.

Comment: but there is no search bar. Its difficult to search the 2.3.8 docs

Answer (score 1):

After following the instructions from jdl, I found a way to generate the guides. To do so, install RedCloth, create a project, freeze rails (2.3.2 was the highest I could get it to work for), and generate the guides.

```
sudo gem install -v4.1.1 RedCloth
rails RailsDoc
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.3.2
rake doc:guides
```

The guides are located in doc/guides

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own local copy.

http://wellrounded.wordpress.com/2007/03/11/rails-creating-a-local-copy-of-the-api-documentation/

Comment: This works for generating the API documentation, but not the guides (as far as I can tell. I just followed the instructions). It helped me on my way to finding a solution though. Thanks.