# Where to find the Rails Guide for Rails 2.3.x now that the official Rails Guide is updated with Rails 3 Guide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The guide at

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

There doesn't seem to have a link to link back to older guides.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to find old Rails 2.3 Guides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604929/where-to-find-old-rails-2-3-guides)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://railsapi.com/, just click "build your custom package" and then select 2.3.x from the dropdown. I'd also recommend downloading it from that site as well, since it does seem that 2.3.x docs are becoming harder to come by.